# clear app data without killing application

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I need to clear all app data including cache without killing the application. All solutions I have seen either just remove cache data or they kill the application after removing app data. Is there any way to do aforementioned thing without the application being closed?

Comment: what exactly you are trying to achieve? What is the scenario? You want to clear complete app data or just want to clear whatever data you stored?

Comment: I want to complete complete app data, like you would get when you do when you do the following: Settings->Applications-> ManageApplications-> My_application-> Clear Data

Comment: To my knowledge, it's not possible. There might be some system functions working with that data. It is better to clear the data specifically which you don't need.

Answer (score 0):

Android developers save user data mainly in three locations. `File System` `DataBase` `SharedPreference`.

**File System**

```
context.getCacheDir();
context.getFilesDir();
context.getExternalCacheDir();
context.getExternalFilesDir();
```

You can navigate the file system and delete the file you create.

**Database**

You can use `context.deleteDatabase(String name);` to delete the database you create.

**SharedPreference**

`context.getSharedPreferences(String name, int mode).edit().clear();` will remove all values in the sharedpreference file.

Indeed, it's your responsibility to find all the files and directories your app creates. I think it's hard to do it exactly right.

And with the application running, it generates new files when you are cleaning the room. So the methods above can provide your user a way to minimize storage usage, but can not really completely remove all data.